# Use equations to create a realistic problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, kinematics, projectile

Given the following equations:

$100$ m = $0$ m + ($50 \cos\theta$ m/s)$t_1$

$0$ m = $0$ m + ($50 \sin\theta$ m/s)$t_1$ - $\frac{1}{2}(9.80$ m/s<sup>2</sup>$) t_1^2$

I am supposed to make up/create a real-life problem in which these equations are true.

### -------------------------------------------

The only thing I recognize is that $\cosθ$ represents something in the x-direction, and that $\sinθ$ represents something in the y-direction.

I recognize that gravity is involved in the equations $\frac{1}{2}(9.80 m/s^2)$, but I am having a hard time visualizing what it all means.

Could someone explain to me what is going on in this equation?

Is it saying that an object travels a distance of 100 m, and that I am trying to find the angle it was launched at (hence using the $\cos$ and $\sin$)?

I am using my textbook and have been trying to find examples of these equations in use, but I am finding myself lost.

Comment: Think of a mass sliding down a smooth incline.

Comment: Your second equation is incorrect.  In addition, your equations are numeric rather than symbolic ... which makes them practically useless.

Comment: I'm not sure the numeric values given in the second equation would suit a mass sliding down an incline. The fact that the object starts and finishes at 0m in the $y$-direction but has non-zero total translation in the $x$-direction implies that it is a projectile of sorts. A mass sliding down a smooth incline would imply a starting position of $y_{initial} > y_{final}$, which isn't the case in the example.

Comment: @DavidWhite -- I'm not sure the second equation is incorrect. Doesn't it just come from $S=ut+0.5at^{2}$, but with an additional constant which may be interpreted as an initial vertical displacement (in this case, 0)?

Comment: @DavidWhite It isn't. Two equations in two variables. $t\approx 2.041$ and $\theta\approx 0.201$ is one solution.

Comment: 0 = 0 + a_whole_lot_of_additional_stuff?  Give me a break!

Comment: @DavidWhite -- Unnecessary in this situation, but that doesn't make it wrong. The additional constant is necessary when, for example, considering trajectories of objects shot over a cliff using sea level as zero. In this situation you would then have $y = y_{\rm{cliff}} + ut - 0.5gt^{2}$. I think it was just included in this situation as a red herring so that the homework question was a bit harder. If you are suggesting that it's impossible to have 0  = 0 +something1+something2, then that's obviously false if something1 = -something2...

Comment: The WHOLE point is this:  I teach high school physics, and have been for the past 11 years.  Students almost automatically default to a numeric way of thinking, which GREATLY hinders the underlying concepts.  If the OP can't manage to think in terms of the equations that match his statement, it will be very difficult to answer his question in a way that gets the key concept across to him (or her).  Based on the implied level of thinking that is required from the original problem statement, a numeric way of thinking is totally inappropriate.

Comment: @JamesFreehan, I have another comment.  The arguments for sin and cos functions MUST be dimensionless.  I just tried to "back out" the equations involved in the original problem statement, and I can't.  BOTH starting equations are incorrect.

Comment: My point was that it is just an intercept, and in general is not wrong/unnecessary. I agree with the statement that a numeric way is generally very bad, and I'm not advocating it (and if this is a homework question it's a stupid one, imo), but that was the nature of the question which was asked.

Comment: @DavidWhite As far as I can see the arguments for sin and cos do come out as dimensionless (although it is now nearly 3am here). Using the first equation you can get $t=2/ \cos(\theta)$ in sec. Plug this into the second equation to get (after rearranging and cancelling) $50\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) = 9.8$, and both sides should have units of metres. Using $\sin(2\theta) = 2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$ then gets you to $25\sin(2\theta) = 9.8$, again both sides with units of metres. Rearrange to get $\sin(2\theta) = 9.8 m/25 m$ which is dimensionless, so you can get the angle.

Comment: Yeah, the problem comes from a textbook.
Here's a snap of the actual problem, in case you're interested. 

https://i.imgsafe.org/67e22e1.png

Comment: @defaultname, if possible, you should choose another textbook.  Any author of a textbook who is as sloppy as the posed question indicates, should not be an author that you learn physics from.

Comment: Dang, really? That's not good! Especially for an introductory University Physics class. haha
It's called 
"Physics for Scientists and Engineers: A Strategic Approach"
Third Edition
by Randall D Knight.

Comment: @DavidWhite I don't see what you see. The equations are a direct mirror of the usual $v_t = v_0 + a t$ and its integral, $x_t = x_0 + v_0 t + \frac12 a t^2$, where someone unhelpfully substituted a mix of numbers and trig functions. The equations are not so badly disguised as to be unrecognizable; and by including some apparently superfluous terms, the similarity is better maintained. And dimensionally they are fine. $(50 \cos\theta) m/s$ has dimensions of meters per second ; multiply by time and you have distance. I completely agree that in general the early substitution of numbers is bad.

Comment: @defaultname, Randal Knight is supposedly an excellent author.  IF the posted photocopy of the problem came from his book, I may well change my opinion regarding this author.  I am teaching from a similar text, from Tipler, and in the whole text, there are NO problems that look like the one you posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are a couple of classical equations of motion derived from Newton's laws, dealing with the motion of a body with initial velocity of 50 m/s at an angle of $\theta$ degrees (or radians) with respect to the horizontal/ground/$x$-axis, assuming that the coordinate system is flat. The object is subject to a downwards acceleration, which we infer is due to the Earth's gravitational pull. The first equation should run as follows:

\begin{equation}
x_{\rm{final}} = x_{\text{initial}} + v_{\rm{initial,\ x}}t_{1}.
\end{equation}

i.e., final displacement of the object is equal to the sum of the initial displacement and the displacement that it gained travelling at velocity $v_{\rm{initial,\ x}} = 50\cos(\theta)$ m/s in time $t_1$. The second equation deals with motion of the same object in the $y$-direction, which is where gravity comes into effect. The equation is:

\begin{equation}
y_{\rm{final}} = y_{\rm{initial}} + v_{\rm{initial,\ y}}t_1 - a_yt_1^{2}.
\end{equation}

We know from the second equation that the starting and finishing position in the $y$-direction is 0 m, but that the object is displaced by 100 m in the $x$-direction. You have a pair of simultaneous equations here as you have two equations and two unknowns ($\theta$, the launch angle, and $t_1$, the time of flight), so you can solve for both. Basically, a realistic scenario would be anything which sensibly fits the values you get when you solve the system of equations, e.g., someone throwing a rock, or something... Feel free to use your imagination here.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!
I think I might understand what's going on here, then.


Correct me if I'm wrong, but I tried drawing a diagram of what's happening (so I could visualize it better). So basically, the object travels at 50m/s, displacing 100ft, starting from 0 elevation and landing at 0 elevation. 


The unknowns in the equation are time (t). So in other words, I am supposed to figure out approximately how long the object was in the air?

https://i.imgsafe.org/95e370b.png

Comment: You are correct, apart from there are *two* unknowns, those being $t$, the time of flight, and $\theta$, the launch angle. I think that someone has given possible answers for them in a comment above. You need to figure out both of these to fully satisfy the system of equations. I think that your diagram is also correct, except again that you have missed of $\theta$ from your velocity arrow (which should be measured with respect to the $x$-axis).

Answer (score 0):

The equations look like the displacement of an object subject to zero acceleration (first equation) or the acceleration of gravity (second equation). If we assume that the first equation represents horizontal motion and the second, vertical motion (suggested by the 9.80 m/s$^2$), we can try to come up with a scenario.

By inspection of equation (1) we see that the object appears to start from rest, and reaches a distance of 100 m at time $t_1$, having had a constant horizontal velocity of $50 \cos\theta m/x$

Now looking at equation (2), it seems that the object started and stopped at a $y$ of 0 m, having had an initial vertical velocity of $50\sin\theta m/s$.

This looks a lot like a projectile fired with velocity of 50 m/s at an angle $\theta$ such that it hits the ground at a distance of 100 m.

A bit of rearranging of the second equation gives

$$t_1 = 100 \sin \theta /9.80$$

substituting that into the first equation, you get an expression for theta:

$$ 100 = 50 \cos\theta \cdot (100 \sin\theta / 9.80)$$

Using $\sin 2\theta = 2\sin\theta\cos\theta$, this can be rewritten as

$$ \sin 2\theta = \frac{9.80}{25}$$

which gives $\theta = 11.5°$ or $\theta = 78.5°$. Two possible answers because you could swap the $\sin$ and $\cos$ and the equation would look the same. A

Now a velocity of 50 m/s is quite large - this is not a speed you can typically reach with a throw (fastest baseball pitch ever clocked, by Aroldis Chapman, went 47 m/s). But golf balls can be hit at speeds up to 80 m/s. So this might be what happens if an average golfer hit a golf ball in vacuum with a driver (loft angles between 8 and 13 degrees). I say "in vacuum" because golf balls get considerable lift from their spin (Magnus effect).